# Question about the VEGAS-algorithm for numerical integration

Tags: computational-physics, integration

**Disclaimer:** I am not quite sure if this question belongs to Physics SE, if not feel free to move it.

**Question:**
I am currently using the VEGAS-algorithm (See e.g. [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(78)90004-9) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEGAS_algorithm)) and i am trying to understand how it works. But in the paper "A New Algorithm for Adaptive Multidimensional Integration" by G. P. Lepage [[J. Comput. Phys. **27** (1978) 192-203]](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(78)90004-9) the description is rather unclear to me at one point.

He states that the steps of the density distibution function are subdivided into $m_i + 1$ subdivisions, where
$$
m_i = K \cdot \frac{\bar f _i \Delta x_i  }{\sum_j \bar f _j \Delta x_j }
$$
where $K \in \mathbb N$ and
$$
\bar{f}_i = \sum_{x \in [x_i - \Delta x_i , x_i)} |f(x)| \approx\frac{1}{\Delta x_i} \int_{x_i - \Delta x_i} ^{x_i} |f(x)| \text{d}x. 
$$
From now on it is not clear to me how the new distribution function is defined, since in the paper he does not explain it (or i do not understand it at least). The author says

> As it is desirable to restore the number of increments to its original value ($=N$), groups of the new increments must be amalgamated into larger increments, the number of subincrements in each group being constant (to preserrve the relative increment density). The net effect is to alter the increment sizes, while keeping the total number constant, so that the smallest increments occur where $|f(x)|$ is largest.

So how are the new bins recombinated from the subdivided bins?